# How should an Angular library interact with code

Tags: angular

I'm writing a library for an Angular app, what is the Angular way to do this? Should it use a service to be consumed by the rest of the application or should I write a plain typescript class with functions to be used?

It's functions would look like this:

```
ConverterLib.convert(100, ConverterLib.UNITS.liters, ConverterLib.UNITS.milliliters)
```

I'd assume using a service because ng generate creates a service in the library folder.

Answer (score -1):

the angular way to do this is to wrap it in service and [module.forRoot](https://medium.com/@chrishouse/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7),

but i assum all your conversion are pure function. So you service is just "wrapper". like this, later, you will be able to use this pure function on any other project without dealing with internal angular code.

```
@NgModule({})
export class ConverterModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ConverterModule,
      providers: [ ConverterService ]
    }
  }
}
```

and on your `app.module`

```
@NgModule({
    import: [
        ConverterModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
export class AppModule{ }
```

and your service should be something like this :

```
@Injectable()
export class ConverterService {

    convert(value, unitFrom, unitTo) {
        switch (unitFrom) {
            case ConverterLib.UNITS.liters:
                return this.convertFromLiters(value, unitTo);
            // [...]
        }
    }

    protected convertFromLiters(value, unitTo) {
        switch (unitTo) {
            case ConverterLib.UNITS.milliliters:
                return convertLitersToMilliliters(value); // Pure function
        }
    }
}
```

[What is pure function ?](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976)